# Determining which polygon(s) each point lies in using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, overlay, point-in-polygon

I am using QGIS software. I have shapefile layer of points and a shapefile layer of polygons(many of them overlapping). I need to determine which polygon(s) each point lies in.

I tried "Join attributes by location" with the solution posted here:([How to find the polygon inside which a point lies?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62219/how-to-find-the-polygon-inside-which-a-point-lies)). My question is different because many of my points will be inside multiple polygons. This only gives one polygon per point. My solution will have many polygons for each point.

For example, I would like to know the identity of every blue circle that lies underneath each black dot.

[image]

How can I complete this analysis?

Comment: I think 'Point sampling tool' is what you are looking for :http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137352/is-there-a-identity-analysis-tool-for-qgis

Comment: @user80597 Thanks, but unfortunately this still gives me the same problem.  For each point, it gives me a single polygon. I need all possible polygons for each point.

Comment: I solved this problem.  Simply use the "Intersect" feature under Geoprocessing tools.

Comment: @Mitchell - Consider posting your comment as an answer and then accepting it by clicking the green-faded tick ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. Simply use the "Intersect" feature under Geoprocessing tools.

Comment: Could you please show how you did this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for polygons that don't overlap each other. Maybe that can be edited and used for your case as well:
Added a column to the point layer "poly_id". Filled with the expression:

```
attribute(
  get_feature_by_id(
    'layer_name_polygons',
    array_find(
      array_foreach(
        aggregate( 'layer_name_polygons', 'array_agg', $geometry ),
        intersects( $geometry, @element ) 
      ), '1' ) ), 'id' )
```